# Querying for model based on file name

Tags: django

I've got a filename:

filename = 'myfile.txt'

I'd like to be able to query for it.

```
            summernoteimages = UserFile.objects.filter(
                                                        Q(file__name=filename)
                                                        )
```

I'm getting the following error: Unsupported lookup 'name' for FileField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: Share the model.

Answer (score 1):

```
UserFile.objects.filter(
Q(file__endswith=filename))
```

Or

```
UserFile.objects.filter(
Q(file__icontains=filename))
```